# MVC3/Azure - What's the most scalable way to handle 50k+/second quick API calls?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, api, asynchronous, azure-web-roles

I have a farm of Web Roles running on Azure based on MVC3 that potentially need to handle ~50k API calls per second. The calls will be quick, all they do is adding some data to Azure Storage Queues (I am aware of the quotas there, I do have my queues partitioned). No values/status are returned back to the client by the API. At the moment each call takes around 100-200ms.

Currently I have it setup as an AsyncController, my code is below.

My question to you all - is this the most scalable, efficient and quickest way to handle this type of load?

PS - I have been told that `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` is recommended, true?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class ApiController : AsyncController {
    public void CallAsync(string data) {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment(1);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
           // add to my queue here
           AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
    public void CallCompleted() {}
}
```

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.5 you could make use of async/await which is more suited to I/O bound operations whereas the TPL, Task.Factory... is more suited to CPU bound operations. Adding as a comment, as I know it doesn't completely answer your question, but it's more of a tip.

Comment: Thanks @ianaldo21 - I could easily go to 4.5 but can you elaborate what would I gain by switching to async/await in bit more detail please?

Comment: By using the TPL, you will be using a thread from the ThreadPool and blocking that thread from executing other tasks until it completes. Whereas with async, await will release the ThreadPool thread, you can find out more information here about this and other benefits: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/4b5a0215-4919-4890-9b64-08eb149e6643

Comment: This is huge, big thanks! This way my API calls will return even quicker and I will be able to handle even more load.

Comment: @ianaldo21 - i guess i am still unclear on how to implement what im doing with async/await. Do i still keep my Async Controller as is and just performs my Queue transaction within the async/await or it replaces the whole thing? Thanks for all your help. If you wish to put this as you answer we can do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No values/status are returned back to the client by the API.

This is almost always a mistake. You seriously don't want your clients notified if the value wasn't saved for some reason? Like, say, an [expired Azure Storage certificate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/02/24/windows-azure-service-disruption-from-expired-certificate.aspx)? Are you *sure* that you want your error handling behavior to be "just delete the data and pretend the call never happened"?

For the remainder of this question, I'm going to assume that you do actually want a "fire and forget" API call that will always return success even when it fails, since that's what you specify in your question.

> The calls will be quick, all they do is adding some data to Azure Storage Queues.

There are two different ways you can optimize this: for the average case and for the worst case.

If you want to optimize for the average case, then consider using blocking calls. (gasp!)

The average latency for a properly-administrated Azure Storage Queue is a miniscule 10ms, with a transaction time as low as 0.5ms. With speeds that fast, you're probably better off just blocking the ASP.NET request thread rather than switching to a thread pool thread (or starting up a new thread). Plus, your code becomes quite easy to read:

```
public class ApiController : Controller {
  public void CallAsync(string data) {
    // add to my queue here
  }
}
```

The disadvantage to the blocking method is that if the Queue latency suddenly goes up, your ASP.NET servers will *very* quickly fill up with blocked threads and you'll start 503'ing.

If you want to optimize for the worst case, then you should toss the queueing onto a background thread and then (synchronously) return. You can use the `BackgroundTaskManager` [from my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) to register the background tasks with ASP.NET:

```
public class ApiController : Controller {
  public void CallAsync(string data) {
    BackgroundTaskManager.Run(async () => {
      // add to my queue here
    });
  }
}
```

The advantage of this is that your servers can "buffer" more in memory as background tasks than as threads. So if the Queue latency spikes and then recovers, your web servers will be able to handle it. The disadvantage of this approach is that the requests *may* all be slightly slower than the synchronous version.

> PS - I have been told that TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning is recommended, true?

Absolutely not in the way you're using it. Your current code is actually creating a new thread for each incoming request - very inefficient. `LongRunning` should only be used when creating tasks that are long-running.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the last comment on the question. There will be no need to derive from the AsyncController or use the Async/Completed conventions. If I were to rewrite your code taking advantage of async/await it would look like this:

```
    public class ApiController : Controller
    {
       public async Task Call(string data)
       {
           await SomeUpdateMethod(data).ContinueWith(returnedData =>
            {
                if (returnedData.Result)
                {
                    //Log success or return confirmation to client
                }
                else
                {
                    //Log failure or return failure message to client
                }
            });
       }

       private Task<bool> SomeUpdateMethod(string data)
       {
           var result = false;
           //Push onto queue and if succesfull set result to true
           return Task.FromResult(result);
       }
   }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: So just to clarify, if the SomeUpdateMethod takes 10 seconds to run, the client will also have to wait that long but this is about releasing the Thread back to the pool while it's processing. Once the processing is done, Thread it taken back and used to return the value?

Comment: That's right, the client will have to wait. However, the client/UI thread will not be blocked, and the client can continue to function and create new tasks to be used on the thread pool etc. Once the thread on the thread pool returns, the result is synced back with the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you need your controller to start the enqueue operation and then return the response immediately. The response doesn't take into account if the queue operation is successful or fails.

This means that you only need the queue operation to be asynchronous and not the controller itself. I don't have experience with Azure Storage Queue, but if I got the correct [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee772736.aspx), it looks like it is using the traditional .Net Asynchronous Programming Model (APM - based on Begin/End methods) rather than the more modern Event-based asynchronous pattern (EAP - based on methods sufixed with 'Async').

So your code could look something like this:

```
public void Call(string data)
{ 
    // Some synchronous code here

    cloudQueue.BeginAddMessage(message // your message object
        , iar => { } // callback method executed after the async operation is finished. The controller does not wait for this
        , state // an object to be transmited to callback
    );
}
```

BeginAddMessage uses asynchronous I/O, which means that it doesn't consume any thread pool thread while executed. The callback method, received as the second parameter, will be executed on a thread pool thread as soon as the asynchronous operation is finished. If you don't need the callback, pass the parameter as null.

In the above code, the controller returns a response immediately after starting BeginAddMessage. That is because the controller is not asynchronous and it doesn't wait for asynchronous operations inside it to complete.

If you needed to make the controller wait for BeginAddMessage to complete (which would have been needed if the API response needed to reflect the success or failure of the enqueue operation), then you would have had to make your controller asynchronous by adding the async keyword to it and await for on the call to BeginAddMessage(you would have needed [TaskFactory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321472.aspx) for that). You can read more about using asynchronous methods in ASP .Net MVC [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Behind the scenes, BeginAddMessage makes a HTTP call to the [Azure REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179363.aspx). .Net limits the number of concurrent calls to an HTTP host using ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit, which by default is set to 2. You might want to increase that value in order to increase the throughput from your application. Keep in mind however that increasing to a very high value would also have negative effects on performance and reliability (I have recently published an [article](http://www.ducons.com/blog/tests-and-thoughts-on-asynchronous-io-vs-multithreading) that touches this aspect). Probably the a good value would be somewhere around 100 but that is always dependent on your application / hosting environment.

One last thing to keep in mind regarding asynchronous calls from your controllers is that they might make your API behave in a misleading way. Your API will be able to deliver a very big number big calls / second, but behind the scenes you might reach the scalability limits of the Azure Storage Queues. Calls to BeginAddMessage are internally queued up based on ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit, so this will hold very well to a big number of calls over a short period of time, but if the number of calls / second that your API receives is constantly higher than what the Storage Queue can deliver, then your application will simply break at some point, loosing a very large number of received messages (which didn't get the chance to be persisted in the queue).